# How to fast check if price of a stock crossed some set of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I am trying to build small app for checking if stock price crosses some alert which can be set in the program.

Alert values are in some kind of a set or array or a binary search tree.

Example:
Bitcoin is at 45000. My alerts are [42500,44000,46000,47000]. I pull the price from somewhere every 2 seconds and price is 43900.
Price has crossed 44000 alert.

My idea:
lets have price delta which will be difference between curr price and prev price.
If delta is positive then i should check if nearest smaller number then current price is in range:
prev_price <= thatNumber <= curr_price
and if it is then i should print that price has crossed that alert. Analog for the other situation.

My question is what is the best method to implement search for this problem or best idea. I wanted to use AVL binary search tree for storing alerts and new alerts that should be inserted later.
Plan is to be scalable to 100 alerts so maybe this is overkill.
What do you guys think, is this a good efficient idea for checking if price has crossed the value?

Answer (score 0):

I would stick the numbers in a database and use an index.

For example using [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) from the Python standard library, you can create tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE alarms (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    stock_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_alarms_name on alarms(name);
CREATE INDEX idx_alarms_stock_price on alarms(stock_id, price);
```

Insert into it.  Then query what alarms got triggered by a price change with a call like this:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT *
    FROM alarms
    WHERE stock_id = :stock_id
      AND min(:price1, :price2) <= price
      AND price <= max(:price1, :price2)
    """, {"stock_id": 5, "price1": 50, "price2": 100})
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Under the hood the index will be some kind of ordered binary tree that knows how to do a range search.  But those implementation details you don't have to worry about.